# Don't weighted LinearLayouts support round-rect backgrounds?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I experienced some awkward behavior. The LinearLayout below is assigned the correct background, but all corner radiis are simply dismissed. The question is why, and how do I solve this? If I set the `android:background` on the `TextView` it works fine.

Why do I wrap the TextView in a LinearLayout at all? I want to animate the TextView's text. Only the text, not the background, so I wrapped it into a LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/summary_title_horizontal_last" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/evaluation_highscore_title"
                style="@style/Summary.Title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/evaluation_highscore"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

`@drawable/summary_title_horizontal_last`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="@color/summary_title_start"
        android:endColor="@color/summary_title_end"
        android:angle="270" />

    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/summary_box_radius"  />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your `TextView` is not drawing the background in a solid corner? You don't seem to have padding in your `LinearLayout` to keep the children away from the corners, so that they don't redraw the background (though I don't know what's in your `Summary.Title` style - you could be using margins there).

Hierarchy Viewer is invaluable in cases like this, since you can see what each view is drawing, against different backgrounds.

Comment: Too stupid to be true. Yes, the TV's style sets the same background, but *without* any rounded corners. Simple overdraw.